# Transformar Inner Join bruto para Join do Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Estou atualizando um sistema que é desenvolvido em PHP puro e estou colocando ele em Laravel, porém, nunca tinha feito mais de um join e com parametros "AND" por isso gostaria que me ajudassem, como posso colocar esse SELECT no controller do Laravel?

```
<?php 
  $users = "SELECT * FROM ma_usuario u, ma_user_tipo t, ma_user_tipo_rel r 
            WHERE ma_user_tipo.tp_usr_id=ma_user_tipo_rel.tp_usr_id 
            AND ma_usuario.usr_id=ma_user_tipo_rel.usr_id 
            AND ma_usuario.usr_status='Ativo' 
            AND r.tp_usr_id='$id' 
            ORDER BY u.usr_id";
 ?>
```

Como são vários parâmetros tive um nó no cérebro e não entendi como montar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo a documentação (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins) você pode fazer a sua query dessa forma:

```
DB::table('ma_usuario')
    ->join('ma_user_tipo_rel' 'ma_usuario.usr_id', '=', 'ma_user_tipo_rel.usr_id')
    ->where([
        ['ma_usuario.usr_status', '=', 'Ativo'],
        ['ma_user_tipo_rel.tp_usr_id', '=', $id],
    ])
    ->orderBy('ma_usuario.usr_id');
```

Comment: Obrigado!! Eu li e reli a documentação e não estava compreendendo como aplicava o where.

Comment: De nada. Dá pra usar dois where's separados também, eu acabei juntando os dois por praticidade.